# Add an option to a select element in second place

Tags: jquery

I search to know how place a new select element at the second place of a select list

*The hierarchy:*

- first : white element
- second : my new element (there : Add)
- next : my email list

*My function :*

```
function classAppend(){
    $('#email').append(
        $('<option></option>').val('').addClass('new_address_mail').html("Add")
    );
}
```

Some one know what is the option?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#email option:first').after($('<option />', { "value": '', text: 'My new option', class: 'new_address_mail' }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to select the first child of `#email` and insert your element with `insertAfter`:

```
$('<option></option>')
   .val('')
   .addClass('new_address_mail')
   .html("Add")
   .insertAfter($('#email').children().first());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `insertBefore` and without the children?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<option value='x'>newly added</option>").insertAfter($("select option:first"));​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/DPBzN/)